# how to change the structure of the schemetic components in altium designer

Tags: schematics, altium

I downloaded a library for microchip PIC18F in altium designer. The schematic component for PIC18F2455 is show in the figure (left).

[image]

But what I want is the component looks like - right part of the figure. How to change the structure of the schematic component?

Comment: if you don't know how to create schematic library, then follow this link. http://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADOH/Creating+Library+Components+Tutorial

Answer (score 1):

If you create your own SchLib file, and open the vendor's IntLib file containing the component that you want to copy, then you can copy & paste components out of the IntLib into your SchLib and then edit them as you please.

Right click on the component entry in the vendor SchLib sidebar to copy, and right click again in your own library's component list to paste.